# WCF 4.0 Routing

Tags: wcf

Scenario:
We have a WCF 4.0 web service which basically accepts the request and puts the messages to production Queue. We also have same UAT and DEV webservices which puts messages to UAT and DEV Queues.... The problem with this setup is that third party vendor who invokes these web services have only one environment setup on their end. This means they won't be able to invoke DEV or UAT once everything is in Production. This has caused us an issue of not being able to test for any enhancements...

We have a requirement to create another layer of WCF 4.0 which acts as a proxy. This basically reads the request message and based on FLAG it then routes the request to either PROD,UAT or DEV.

Could anyone please suggest how this can be achieved using WCF 4.0? One way I can think of is using proxy of PROD, UAT and DEV and invoke them based on FLAG i mentioned above. This solution I think works but I'm wondering if there's way to achieve above with out creating proxy.

Answer (score 0):

WCF Routing would be good here.

Basic coverage to get an idea is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd795218.aspx

I used it to switch which workflow of several to use based on a passed in parameter.

My experience was that all the switching can occur in configuration and none had to be in code.  Some complex scenarios might benefit from code based switching which is also possible, but only as a last resort.